# Цвет пикселя по заданным координатам

Tags: c#

Как можно получить цвет пикселя по координатам x и y ?

Или обязательно делать скриншот ?

И можно ли делать скриншот одного пикселя.

Comment: Цвет пикселя где? В вашем приложении или в чужом? Поконкретнее!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я бы уточнил если бы это было что то конкретно, нужно в любом месте на экране, моём - не моём - без разницы.

Comment: вот нужная вам функция winapi. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx Как подключать и использовать винапи функции в шарпе уже нагуглите сами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключим для начала WinAPI, а именно [BitBit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDc, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);
```

Далее создадим метод, который будет возвращать цвет:

```
public System.Drawing.Color GetColorAt(System.Drawing.Point location)
{
    var screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (var gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
    {
        using (var gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            IntPtr hSrcDc = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hDc = gdest.GetHdc();
            BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, 1, 1, hSrcDc, location.X, location.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
}
```

Ну и вызываем

```
var color = GetColorAt(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
```

---

Источник [En SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483963/6808809).

Answer (score 1):

```
Color c = (pictureBox.Image as Bitmap).GetPixel(x, y);
```